# How to check if pod security policy is enabled?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to debug why pod security policy (psp) isn't applying. Running the following shows no resources found. Not sure if this is sufficient to confirm psp is enabled.

```
$ kubectl get psp
No resources found.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you create a psp?

Comment: i think if you have defined one , it should show up , it is not namespaced

Comment: yes I can add a psp fine. But I am not really sure why its not taking into effect. Here is my issue related to this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70513 I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not enough to prove it's enabled, as mentioned Ijaz by quoting the documentation.

On GCP, you can do that :

```
gcloud beta container clusters describe $CLUSTER_NAME  --zone $CLUSTER_ZONE | grep -A 1 podSecurityPolicyConfig
```

If enabled, the expected output is :

```
podSecurityPolicyConfig:
  enabled: true
```

Otherwise you'll get something like that:

```
podSecurityPolicyConfig: {}
privateCluster: true
```

Answer (score 5):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#enabling-pod-security-policies

> Pod security policy control is implemented as an optional (but
>   recommended) admission controller. PodSecurityPolicies are enforced by
>   enabling the admission controller, but doing so without authorizing
>   any policies will prevent any pods from being created in the cluster.
>
> Since the pod security policy API (policy/v1beta1/podsecuritypolicy)
>   is enabled independently of the admission controller, for existing
>   clusters it is recommended that policies are added and authorized
>   before enabling the admission controller.